# Webpack: Why does vue-loader not transpile?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-loader

I am using vue-loader V14 and Webpack 3.12.  In the vue-loader documentation is says that javascript will automatically be transpiled using babel-loader, but when I look at the output I still see ES6, such as:

```
data() {
    return {
        current: ''
    };
},
```

Here's the (relevant parts of) the webpack config:

```
resolve: {
    alias: {
      'vue$': 'vue/dist/vue.esm.js'
    }
},
module: {
    rules : [
        {
            test: /\.js$/,
            use: {
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                options: {
                    presets: ['env']
                }
            }
        },
        {
            test: /\.vue$/,
            use: 'vue-loader'
        }
    ]
}
```

I have tried setting the `vue$` alias to point to the `vue.common.js` version.

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE: Here's another config I tried for the vue-loader rule:

```
{
    test: /\.vue$/, 
    loader: "vue-loader",
    options: {
        loaders: { js: 'babel-loader' }
    }
}
```

Comment: Per the OP, vue-loader V14, which does not have a plugin, AFAIK.

Comment: You might be reading the docs for the newer version of vue-loader. For V14, your config won't work, you need to explicitly list babel-loader in vue-loader's options for js files. [This](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/migrating.html#loader-inference) is how it was changed in V15.

Comment: @DecadeMoon, I tried that (per the update above).  Still no joy.

Comment: It needs to be `{ options: { loaders: { js: 'babel-loader' } } }`.

Comment: @DecadeMoon, Yep, I found that and fixed it.  (Now updated in the code above).  Still no joy.  It's absolutely unbelievable that it can be this hard!

Comment: @DecadeMoon, I just found that the problem exists in my plan JS files as well, so not related to vue-loader.  Perhaps I need to reinstall the babel-loader?

Comment: Now I have normal JS files working fine, but the problem with Vue files still exists... not sure what changed...

Answer (score 0):

I had to set this preset in `.babelrc`

```
"presets": [
    ["env", { "modules": "commonjs" }]
],
```