# Is the shorthand ES6 method syntax also valid ES5?

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vue-loader

Here's the snippet (from a Vue configuration object):

```
data() {
    return {
        current: ''
    };
},
```

I've two entirely separate projects that are supposed to be transpiled with Babel, however both outputs still include above syntax. Webpack and Babel are well above my pay grade, or am I mistaken about what is valid ES5?.

One of the projects is the subject of this question, [Webpack: Why does vue-loader not transpile?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52107186/webpack-why-does-vue-loader-not-transpile?noredirect=1#comment91165249_52107186), and the other is a fresh install using vue-cli.

UPDATE:

Here's the syntax I was expecting in the output.

```
data : function () { 
    return {}; 
}
```

UPDATE 2:

This link from MDN seems to make it pretty clear that it is ES6 only, https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Method_definitions

Comment: What syntax you expecting?

Comment: Good point @EdmundReed.  See update above.

Comment: @KimPrince Feel free to answer your own question. Others with the same question might find your answer useful.

Comment: Your code is not being transpiled for some reason.    But your expected syntax above is not correct either.  It would be `data: function data() {...` once transpiled by bable

Comment: In this, you can read the correct markup which is that you expect after the transpilation: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#components-demo. If you want to shorten it, you can use: data: ()=> ({ current: '' })

Comment: What do you have in your .babelrc file?

Answer (score 0):

your syntax is valid ES5 and also ES6. In your component configuration, `data` is a key to the configuration object, so the correct format is:

```
data: function(){
  return {
    some_key: some_value
  }
}
```

In ES6 syntax you could write:

```
data: ()=>{ return { some_key: some_value}}
```